# How can I redirect a page to itself in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect, reload

Here is my current code which does redirecting:

```
window.location.href= '/post/' + data.main_id + '/' + subject + '#post-' +  data.post_id;
```

Code above just changes the slug when I'm in the same URL. anyway, I need to both change the slug and reload the page. How can I do that by JS or even jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by first appending the fragment to the URL, then reloading the page:

```
window.location.href += '#post-' + data.post_id;
window.location.reload();
```

Note however that you could improve this further by using [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) and avoiding the need to reload the page at all when the fragment changes.

Comment: Well this is great .. thank you, upvote, but sometimes I'm not always in the same page .. I mean, sometimes I need to redirect *(not just changing the slug)* ..

Comment: In which case you don't need to `reload()` at all: `window.location.assign('foo.html#post-12345')`

Comment: Well using `assign()` doesn't reload when we are in the same page ..! You know, I need a code which **always** *(always means both when I'm in the same page and when I'm in the other page)** both reload the page and change the slug.

Comment: There's no solution for that. When you're on the current page you have to use the append and `reload()` solution in my answer. When redirecting to a different page, you need `assign()` as in my previous comment. As I stated before though, using `pushState` is a much more elegant solution to your issues, but will probably require re-writing your code base.

Comment: I did it .. and I've written an answer.

Comment: How is that any different to my answer?

Comment: Your answer won't work for a totally different urls .. you have just change the slug

Comment: 'How can I ***redirect a page to itself*** in JavaScript?'

Comment: Just for my information, is there any different between `window.location.assign('foo.html#post-12345');` and `window.location.href = 'foo.html#post-12345';`

Comment: No, they have the same end result. Personally I prefer using `assign()` as it'a a method

Comment: I see, also as a note, `.replace()` would work I think `:-)` you can use it too if you like `;-)`

Comment: `replace()` is slightly different in that it removes the current page from the history stack

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
location.reload();
```

Please, see
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: 1) What about changing the `#` fragment in the URL? 2) Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. The information they provide is often outdated, and sometimes even completely incorrect. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is far more comprehensive and reliable.

Comment: pushState() maybe a better sollution for changing URL, instead of window.location.href, more details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API